# Adding hours to DateTime values from different time zones

Tags: r, datetime

While I have found a number of informative posts concerning `POSIXct` and other time functions in R, I am still struggling with time conversions with multiple time zones.

My time is stored as a number from an excel file, is in GMT, and is included below.

```
Data <- structure(list(DateTime = c(40361.584526, 40361.667836, 40361.751285, 
40361.834421, 40361.917986, 40362.000972, 40362.084479, 40362.167396, 
40362.252257, 40362.335301, 40362.417211, 40362.500926, 40362.585185, 
40362.668796, 40362.751655, 40362.834664, 40362.917847, 40363.001007, 
40363.084641, 40363.1675, 40363.251123, 40363.334803, 40363.417616, 
40363.502095, 40363.584514, 40363.667639, 40363.750625, 40363.834225, 
40363.917743, 40354.335405, 40737.501782, 40603.917292, 40604.000556, 
40604.083808, 40604.167292, 40604.250579, 40604.33375, 40604.417164, 
40604.500625, 40604.584074, 40604.666968, 40604.750613, 40604.834306, 
40604.917211, 40605.000625, 40605.083958, 40605.167245, 40605.250567, 
40605.333924, 40605.417488, 40605.500694, 40605.584306, 40605.66728, 
40605.750718, 40605.834236, 40605.917905, 40606.000625, 40606.083901, 
40606.167292, 40606.250509, 41271.500544, 40048.917037, 40049, 
40049.085926, 40049.583704, 40049.666667, 40049.74963, 40049.832593, 
40051.666667, 40051.752593, 40051.835556, 40051.918519, 40052.001482, 
40052.167407, 40052.25037, 40052.333333, 40052.416296, 40052.751111, 
40052.834074, 40052.917037, 40053, 40053.082963, 40053.168889, 
40053.251852, 40053.334815, 40053.417778, 40053.500741, 40053.583704, 
40053.666667, 40054.084444), StudyArea = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Cali", "Colo", "Pata"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("DateTime", "StudyArea"), row.names = c(NA, 
-90L), class = "data.frame")
```

The head is here:

```
 > head(data)
  DateTime StudyArea
1 40361.58      Cali
2 40361.67      Cali
3 40361.75      Cali
4 40361.83      Cali
5 40361.92      Cali
6 40362.00      Cali
```

I first changed the DateTime to a `POSIXct` in GMT object using the code

```
Data$TimeGMT <- as.POSIXct(Data$DateTime * (60*60*24), origin="1899-12-30", tz="GMT")
```

My goal is to subtract 8, 7, and 4 hours from the TimeGMT's from Cali, Colo, and Pata respectively.  My working code is below, but results in obviously incorrect local dates.

```
LocalDateTime <- as.POSIXct(ifelse(Data$StudyArea == "Cali", Data$TimeGMT - 8*60*60,
    ifelse(Data$StudyArea == "Colo", Data$TimeGMT - 7*60*60,
    Data$TimeGMT  - 4*60*60)),origin="1899-12-30")
```

I suspect there is an easier way to do this and appreciate any help with coding or where to find a list of the R timezone formats as I have not been able to locate one on the `timezone()` help file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
LocalDateTime <- as.POSIXct(ifelse(Data$StudyArea == "Cali", Data$TimeGMT - 8*60*60,
    ifelse(Data$StudyArea == "Colo", Data$TimeGMT - 7*60*60,
    Data$TimeGMT  - 4*60*60)), origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT")
```

Note that we use the standard POSIX origin here. That's because your dates have already been converted to POSIX values from the excel version. So the Excel origin doesn't matter any more. We also need to keep the time zone at GMT otherwise the default is to adjust for your local tz. Doing this gives

```
head(cbind(Data, LocalDateTime))

  DateTime StudyArea             TimeGMT       LocalDateTime
1 40361.58      Cali 2010-07-02 14:01:43 2010-07-02 06:01:43
2 40361.67      Cali 2010-07-02 16:01:41 2010-07-02 08:01:41
3 40361.75      Cali 2010-07-02 18:01:51 2010-07-02 10:01:51
4 40361.83      Cali 2010-07-02 20:01:33 2010-07-02 12:01:33
5 40361.92      Cali 2010-07-02 22:01:53 2010-07-02 14:01:53
6 40362.00      Cali 2010-07-03 00:01:23 2010-07-02 16:01:23
```

An easier way would be

```
LocalDateTime <- Data$TimeGMT - ifelse(Data$StudyArea == "Cali", 8*60*60,
    ifelse(Data$StudyArea == "Colo", 7*60*60, 4*60*60))
```

this way you don't have to worry about the conversion because `ifelse()` isn't dropping the class

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible to avoid using the messy `ifelse`-nesting by choosing an integer to multiply those "hours" by:

```
LocalDateTime <- Data$TimeGMT - 60*60*c(8,7,4)[
                           match(Data$StudyArea , c( "Cali", "Colo","Pata")  )
```